# How can I serve static content from directory outside of webapplication in Jetty7

Tags: jetty

I'm trying to serve static content e.g. pdf file from a directory on unix server that is outside of my web application directory. I have tried the following however I get a 404 when I try to access it. I have defined it as follows in jetty.xml

```
            <Item>
                    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler">
                    <Set name="contextPath">/test</Set>
                    <Set name="handler">
                        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler">
                            <Set name="directoriesListed">true</Set>
                            <Set name="resourceBase">/data/muni/data/AlaBAMa/muMCVClient</Set>
                                                       </New>
                    </Set>
                </New>
            </Item>
```

`/data/muni/data/AlaBAMa/muMCVClient` is path of my server where my pdf file is located. but when I try `/test/test.pdf` I get a 404.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Jetty 7 is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html) - consider upgrading.

Comment: Where is this XML snippet?  just saying `jetty.xml` is not sufficient information.  What `jetty.xml`? found where on disk (or relative path from `${jetty.home}`)? What section did you add it in?  Why did you add it to `jetty.xml` and not use the xml deployables?  what do your other contexts look like (configuration wise)?  do any of them overlap with this new context you want?

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to now upgrade jetty 7 and jett9 which is coming with its own set of problems.. :) currently stuck on following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961466/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-servlet-servletcontext-getservletregistration